# Why can I not format my NSDate with the specified time zone with NSDateFormatter?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

I want to get a date that is represented in a String with a time zone GMT+1 and display it on screen with the local time zone GMT+10.

I have 2 methods, one is for create a date from a String (with GMT+1 timeZone), the other one is to format the date into a String (with localTimeZone GMT+10):

```
func dateFromString(dateString: String) -> NSDate? {
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT+1")
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "M/d/yyyy hh:mma"

    return dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)
}

func stringFromDate(date: NSDate) -> String {
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle

    return dateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)
}
```

In the playground, when I do this:

```
let date = dateFromString("4/8/2015 1:29am")!
println(date)
println(stringFromDate(date))
```

I get the following output on the right side:

```
"Apr 8, 2015, 1:29 AM"
"2015-04-07 15:29:00 +0000"
"1:29 AM"
```

I don't understand why I don't get what I am expecting and looking for:

```
"Apr 8, 2015, 1:29 AM"
"2015-04-08 10:29:00 +0000"
"10:29 AM"
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Why do you expect 1;29 AM GMT+1 to turn into 10:29 GMT?

Comment: I want the date I'm parsing to be shown in the local time which is + 9 more hours. So I thought the way to do it was to parse the date string. When I do it, I specify that this the date will be in GMT+1 and when I format this date, I use GMT+10. It seems I'm wrong somewhere, so how could I get a date in GMT+10 from a date in GMT+1?

Comment: But the middle line in your date lists above is (presumably) the dump of an NSDate object.  That is always shown in UTC.

Comment: It's actually the date I got from parsing the string with `dateFromString`. Ok for the fact that the date is displayed in UTC when using println. But I still don't understand why when I use `println(stringFromDate(date))` I get "1:29 AM" and not "10:29 AM" as I specified the timeZone to be GMT+10 in my `stringFromDate` method.

Comment: Well, you're not showing us all the code, with log statements to print out the input, intermediate steps, and output, so we can't really say.  Eg, where does "Apr 8, 2015, 1:29 AM" come from -- it's inconsistent with everything else.

Comment: A properly constructed question would show ALL of the relevant code along with all relevant logs of input and output data.  And would be consistent, not leaving us to guess what you've modified between your code and the question.

Comment: I gave you everything that is in my playground, I don't see what else you need. "Apr 8, 2015, 1:29 AM" as I wrote it down comes from `let date = dateFromString("4/8/2015 1:29am")!`

Comment: But you say you're "looking for" "Apr 8, 2015, 1:29 AM"??

Comment: No, I didn't say "looking for" "Apr 8, 2015, 1:29 AM" but "looking for" "Apr 8, 2015, 1:29 AM", "2015-04-08 10:29:00 +0000", "10:29 AM". As you explained me, I can't get "2015-04-08 10:29:00 +0000" with `println` on a NSDate. So if you prefer, I would like to have the output "Apr 8, 2015, 1:29 AM" with `let date = dateFromString("4/8/2015 1:29am")!`and "10:29 AM" with `println(stringFromDate(date))`

Comment: So where did "Apr 8, 2015, 1:29 AM" come from??

Comment: That's the automatic output of the playground

Comment: But my point is, that line was telling you something was wrong with the `stringToDate` call.

Comment: Yes but I didn't think the mistake was coming from the GMT+1, that's why I posted my question on SO. Anyway, thanks for taking the time for my case.

Comment: But why did you "expect" that value?

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding. I wrote down both times the full output. I didn't expect the first line of each output to change as I was expecting it to be "Apr 8, 2015, 1:29 AM" for both of them. Why? Because I parsed the string "4/8/2015 1:29am" so I was expecting to get "Apr 8, 2015, 1:29 AM". I don't really follow you there

Comment: But you were parsing 1:29 AM in GMT+1, and the NSTime object is GMT, so it should have been an hour different.

Comment: Ok I got it. Yes indeed it should have been "4/8/2015 10:29am", as the automatic output of the playground seems to format the date using the local time zone. My bad, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Input formatters need the time zone in their string. Like so:

```
func dateFromString(dateString: String) -> NSDate? {
  let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
  dateFormatter.dateFormat = "M/d/yyyy hh:mma z"

  return dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)
}

let date = dateFromString("4/8/2015 1:29am GMT+01")!
```

Also note that NSTimeZone names have a two digit offset. Compare in the playground

```
var oops = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT+1")
var righteous = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT+01")
```

The first is nil, the second is not.

Comment: Thanks! It was the `GMT+1` that was wrong. `GMT+01` fixed it indeed.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't trust the formatting of a time stamp that the debugger prints. In my experience dates are always in UTC regardless of the time zone you set according to the log. Try adding the date as a string to a label on the project and see if it's right.

The reasoning behind this as far as I know is that when you print to the log, all it's doing is calling -description. In the case of NSDate this will return in UTC by definition.

Comment: Actually when I do it in my project (not on a label but using a UIAlertView), it's the same. And when I'm using `println(stringFromDate(date))`, I just print out a String, not a date.